# issue with retrieving hiddenfield value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to retrieve the value of `Hiddenfiedl`. This is generated by `.aspx` so I have to do some asp related stuff

```
     var FolderName = $('#<%= HiddenFieldArticleId.ClientID %>').val();
```

but it shows `undefined`. Not sure why.

this is the html

```
   <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$HiddenFieldArticleId" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenFieldArticleId" value="60380a7e-3048-4b4b-a2a0-86126b1be0cd">
```

Comment: Could you post the generated HTML for your `var FolderName` variable?  I'd like to see the output from your ASP tag.

Comment: I output this with console.log() but it is `undefinied`

Comment: What is "<%= HiddenFieldArticleId.ClientID %>" rendering down to?

Comment: In what order do these two code snippets appear?  If the JavaScript is before the `input` then the `input` doesn't exist when the JavaScript code executes.

Comment: `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenFieldArticleId`..  `var HiddenField = '<%= HiddenFieldArticleId.ClientID %>';
    console.log(HiddenField);
    var FolderName = $('#<%= HiddenFieldArticleId.ClientID %>').val();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set FolderName after the page is fully loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
     var FolderName = $('#<%= HiddenFieldArticleId.ClientID %>').val();
  });

</script>
```